# Reactjs compontent not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a component called `New` twice, one for `/New` another for `/Edit` because all `input` in this page should use for edit page so I decided to use this compontent again but set data with some condition.

**Router**

```
<Route exact path='/New' component={New}></Route>
<Route exact path='/Edit/:id' component={New}></Route>
```

There is no problem for using this component in both pages, but if user be in edit page, and click on `navigation`, see `/New` page with some values that belong to `/Edit` page, this mean page not updated correctly, navigation contains many `<Link/>`

```
<Link to="/New"><Icon name="home"/>New Order</Link>
```

But if I use `window.location.href = "/New"` instead of `<Link/>`, or direct `href` it work fine:

```
<a href="/New"></a>
```

So any idea how can I solve this? I want to update page when I click `<Link/>`.

Comment: did you try this? `<Link onClick={() =>window.location.href = "/New" }><Icon name="home"/>New Order</Link>`

Comment: @SivaKondapiVenkata I don't want to use window location href because it refresh page, I want to use `<Link/>` to switch between pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using condition inside `componentDidMount`; `<Link/>` just switch between component not reload and update component, and you are using one component for two different `route` there is a *! tricky* way to avoid this issue:

```
<div onClick={() => window.location.reload()}><Link to="/New"><Icon name="home"/>New Order</Link></div>
```

*Or/*

```
<Link onClick={this.forceUpdate} to="/New"><Icon name="home"/>New Order</Link>
```

__ Or __

1. Do not use same component for edit
2. *Force* use `window.location.href`

Comment: It work but I don't want to refresh the page, forceUpdate not working, if there is no solution I think should use another component. thanks